# Xubuntu 14.04 fails to resume from hibernation

Tags: 14.04, power-management, hibernate

Not a crucial issue, it's just annoying when it happens. My computer has a great chance to fail in resuming from hibernation.
When it happens, the console prints the following info and then hangs:

> [timestamps] PM: Using 3 thread(s) for decompression.
>   [timestamps] PM: Loading and decompressing image data
>   [timestamps] PM: Image Loading progress: ??%
>   [timestamps] Switched to clocksource tsc
>   [timestamps] random: nonblocking pool is initialized
>   [timestamps] PM: Image loading done.
>   [timestamps] serial 00:05: disabled
>   [timestamps] PM: quiesce of devices complete after 0.387 msec
>   [timestamps] PM: late quiesce of devices complete after 0.140 msec
>   [timestamps] PM: noirq quiesce of devices complete after 0.307 msec
>   [timestamps] Disable non-boot CPUs...
>   [timestamps] Intel_pstate CPU1 exiting
>   [timestamps] smpboot: CPU1 is now offline
>   [timestamps] Disable non-boot CPUs...
>   [timestamps] Intel_pstate CPU2 exiting
>   [timestamps] smpboot: CPU2 is now offline
>   [timestamps] Disable non-boot CPUs...
>   [timestamps] Intel_pstate CPU3 exiting
>   [timestamps] smpboot: CPU3 is now offline

My OS is Xubuntu 14.04.3, kernel version is 3.19.0-28-generic if that matters.

My PC specs: i3 4170, Gigabyte B85M-D3V-A, G.Skill 8G ram and Nvidia GT 630 with nvidia 352 driver installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be a kernel bug. I have this problem with kernel 3.19 and Ubuntu mainline kernel v4.2.3. Downgrading to 3.16 apparently solves the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, hibernate [doesn't work](https://help.ubuntu.com/14.04/ubuntu-help/power-suspendfail.html) in many cases, which can cause you to lose data if you expect your documents and applications to re-open when you switch your computer back on. Therefore, hibernate is disabled by default.

You can find more information about how to fix your problem at [Ubuntu Wiki - Debugging Kernel Hibernate](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebuggingKernelHibernate).

Answer (score 0):

The same bug on ASUS K401L with Ubuntu 14.04.3 running on kernel 3.19.0 and 4.1.13. There is a 1/3 probability of resume failure.

If the resume failed, system will hang with the console output below

```
Disabling non-boot CPUs...
intel_pstate CPU 1 exiting
smpboot: CPU 1 is now offline
intel_pstate CPU 2 exiting
smpboot: CPU 2 is now offline
intel_pstate CPU 3 exiting
smpboot: CPU 3 is now offline
```

Just downgraded to 3.16, it seems work well, but may need further tests.

Comment: I have used kernel 3.16 for more than a month and everything runs flawlessly. Since my hardware is not cutting edge, using a relative old kernel is not a problem.